# List all filetype plugins known to Vim

Tags: vim, filetype

I want to list all filetypes Vim recognizes from its runtimepath.

For example:

```
ada
arc
c
clojure
common-lisp
elisp
go
python
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need those for a custom command that takes filetype arguments, you can just use `:command -complete=filetype`. Else, you can derive the list via the `globpath()` function yourself:

```
echo join(map(split(globpath(&rtp, 'ftplugin/*.vim'), '\n'), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t:r")'), "\n")
```

This gets all ftplugin scripts from the runtimepath, and then modifies the filespec via `fnamemodify()` to only list the root of the filename. `split()` converts into a List, and `join()` back to lines for `:echo`ing.

Comment: Does this take files from `ftplugin/after`, too?

Comment: You mean `after/ftplugin`, and yes, because those are contained in `&rtp`.

Comment: This gives a syntax error on both bash and zsh.

Comment: @mareoraft: Try this inside Vim, not in the shell!